# repeat Select option in ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that repeat select option in ng-repeat. in this form i want to selected defualt value for select element. In fact in first select element selected value is "n1" and in second select element selected value is "n2". while in tow select element defualt value is "n2". 
what is my problem?

```js
function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        orders: [{ s:'' }]
    };

    $scope.list = [1,2];
    $scope.data.orders[0] = "n1";
    $scope.data.orders[1] = "n2";
    $scope.sizes = [ {code: 1, name: 'n1'}, {code: 2, name: 'n2'}];
    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.item.code, $scope.item.name)
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <div ng-repeat="l in list track by $index">
            <select ng-model="data.orders[$index]" ng-change="update()">
                <option ng-selected ="data.orders[$index] == size.name" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
                    {{size.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <select ng-model="data.orders[0]" ng-change="update()">
            <option ng-selected ="data.orders[0] == size.name" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
                {{size.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="data.orders[1]" ng-change="update()">
            <option ng-selected ="data.orders[1] == size.name" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
                {{size.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead. It uses `$parent.$index` instead of `$index`.

`ng-repeat` tracks by  `$index` by default, so there's no need to specify it.

This causes a problem in your inner loop, which is also tracking by `$index`. When you say $index in the inner loop it picks up the inner loops index which is always going to evaluate to true.

```js
function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        orders:[{ s:'' }]
    };
    $scope.list = [1,2];
    $scope.data.orders[0] = "n1";
    $scope.data.orders[1] = "n2";
    $scope.sizes = [{code: 1, name: 'n1'}, {code: 2, name: 'n2'}];
    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.item.code, $scope.item.name)
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <div ng-repeat="l in list track by $index">
            <select ng-model="data.orders[$index]" ng-change="update()">
                <option ng-selected ="data.orders[$parent.$index] == size.name" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
                    {{size.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would just like to comment on the statement that `ng-repeat tracks by $index by default` which is wrong. The default is `track by $id(obj)`. The former tracks by order (fragile if you want to move things around in your array). The latter tracks by identity, and gives each item a $$hasKey to keep them apart. 

Tracking by $index is probably only a good idea if you want to allow duplicate items in your array, or if you are sure you'll never touch the array order.